# Magento 2, Cancels order after credit card payment complete

Tags: magento2.3, credit-card, cancel-orders

I'm facing an interesting issue.
When the customer pays with credit card, magento cancels the order automatically.
I have no idea how it happens tough.
Since i'm newbie, i couldn't find out what is wrong.
Any ideas?

Comment: Check in your used payment method if there is any settings marking the orders as cancelled after payment is done.

Comment: Well, i checked already. All marked as "PENDING"

Answer (score 0):

Which payment method you are using, I have been facing similar issue n PayPal credit card which was occurring from PayPal, I have communicated to them and get it fixed.

The other option is to check return url in the extension configuration and also check the payload return by the card API.

Comment: "When the customer pays with credit card" as mentioned.

Comment: I mean merchant?